# get file location of picture box

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I have a picturebox and I want to pass that to openread() but I get the error path cannot be null. How do I get this working?

```
Dim imageData() As Byte
Dim fileStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(PictureBox1.ImageLocation)
imageData = New Byte((fileStream.Length) - 1) {}
fileStream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
fileStream.Close()
```

Comment: If **you** didn't set the `ImageLocation` it will be null.

Comment: @DonA What if the picture is set from New System.Drawing.Bitmap i'm capturing my desktop to the picture box. where would the location be then?

Comment: null, you have to set it for it not to be null.